# How to change only the protocol part of a java.net.URL object?

Tags: java, http

I have a java.net.URL object that uses the HTTPS protocol, e.g.:

```
https://www.bla.com
```

And I have to change only the protocol part of this URL object so that when I call its toString() method I get this:

```
http://www.bla.com
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll have the use the methods available to you:

```
URL oldUrl = new URL("https://www.bla.com");
URL newUrl = new URL("http", oldUrl.getHost(), oldUrl.getPort(), oldUrl.getFile(), oldUrl.getRef());
```

There's an even more expansive set() method that takes 8 items, you might need that for more elaborate URLs.

Edit: As was just pointed out to me, I wasn't paying attention, and set() is protected. So URL is technically mutable, but to us mortals, it's immutable. So you'll just have to construct a new URL object.

Comment: The `set()` method is protected.

Comment: looks like you took the parameters of the URL.set() method for the constructor, but no such constructor with that prototype actually exists.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. There's no constructor with that signature. URL just stinks

Comment: This answer does not handle cases where the port is not specified and getPort() returns -1 so you have to rely on getDefaultPort()

Answer (score 5):

You can also use string replacement:

```
URL oldUrl = new URL("https://www.bla.com");
String newUrlString = oldUrl.toString().replaceFirst("^https", "http");
URL newUrl = new URL(newUrlString);
```

Answer (score 2):

String url - "`https://www.some-host.com/some-path?somequery=some-value`";

```
String newUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
          .fromUriString(url)
          .scheme("http")
          .build()
          .toUriString();
```

It'll just replace scheme and rest url will remain as-is

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder`/ `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents`

see: [Does there exist a mutable URL/URI object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003574/does-there-exist-a-mutable-url-uri-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It appears they forgot to make their class useful. Stealing code from `URL.toExternalForm()` helps:

```java
public class ICantBelieveThisIsNotInTheStandardLibrary {
    public static final URL makeCopyWithDifferentProtocol(URL u, String protocol) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        result.append(protocol);
        result.append(":");
        if (u.getAuthority() != null && u.getAuthority().length() > 0) {
            result.append("//");
            result.append(u.getAuthority());
        }
        if (u.getPath() != null) {
            result.append(u.getPath());
        }
        if (u.getQuery() != null) {
            result.append('?');
            result.append(u.getQuery());
        }
        if (u.getRef() != null) {
            result.append("#");
            result.append(u.getRef());
        }
        return new URL(result.toString());
    }
}
```

The answer which suggests to use a String-replacement is shorter, but you are going to need something like this if you ever want to change any of the other URL components.